# How to change Switch text to right side in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Android default `Switch` have text and then `Switch` on/off. I'm Expecting `Switch` on/off and then text. Don't use another widgets like `TextView`. How can i set `Switch` right side text.

Comment: Use xml attribute like android:textOn and android:textOff in your xml.

Comment: @JiteshDalsaniya default switch have switch text left side and switch have right side. I'm expecting switch left side and switch text right side.  Can you clear now? what am expecting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set text position to the right of a Switch (like CheckBox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45983522/how-to-set-text-position-to-the-right-of-a-switch-like-checkbox)

Answer (score 39):

[image]

Wrap it in another layout with no text value and add a textview. see my code:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Switch
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/reminder" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Meeting Reminders"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Works great, but how to implement when it is clicked on the `Meeting Reminders` to switch the `Switch` control, Without code logic in the activity? For example `for= "@id/reminder"`

Comment: @keithics Out of context question : Which font is that, used in "Meeting Reminders" ?

Comment: roboto i think, sorry, it was an old project. I cant remember.

Comment: @mihkov Unfortunately it needs to be added in the code, but that is one line:
`linearLayout.setOnClickListener { switch.toggle() }`

Comment: This doesn't play nice with TalkBack

Answer (score 28):

Use

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

Then

```
app:switchPadding="8dp"
```

Comment: This is a dirty hack that I personally do not find advisable, as it will reverse the behavior of the button as well, which will have a negative impact on the user experience.

Comment: I agree with @siyb, "rtl" design is for languages that are written and read from right to left such as arabic.

Comment: `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` is not working for android 11 +

Answer (score 2):

Add this code on Xml file:

```
            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/simpleSwitch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:checked="false"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textOff="@string/no"
                android:textOn="@string/yes"
                android:theme="@style/SCBSwitch" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/switchBtn_txtView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/simpleSwitch"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

In activity Or Fragment :

```
Switch simpleSwitchBtn = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.simpleSwitch);
        final TextView switchBtn_txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.switchBtn_txtView);


        simpleSwitchBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    switchBtn_txtView.setText("Yes");
                }
                else {
                    switchBtn_txtView.setText("No");
                }
            }
        });
```

I think Its helpfull to you....
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the look I wanted with a combination of:

- width (120dp)
- padding (75dp)
- and switchpadding (-90dp)

[image]

Comment: Negative paddings just give me the shivers. But probably this is the only way to do it without extra TextView... Will this give problems in some cases?

Comment: This is the answer you should use https://stackoverflow.com/a/53224113

Comment: I like this answer

Comment: This will break as soon as the text in the switch is changed, which can happen for a number of reasons (app used in a different language, user changing the font scaling on his device, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

This is universal variant for RTL and LTR text modes.
Call it once, for example in method of an Activity `onCreate`.

```
switch.setLayoutDirection( switch.getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL ? View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR : View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL );
```