# Android Switch with 2 lines of text

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

[image]

I am in between creating a settings activity in which i want a switch like the above screenshot. currently my solution is to use two textviews and a switch. is there any straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Switch text to right side in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023350/how-to-change-switch-text-to-right-side-in-android)

Comment: Not quite.i want to set a second line of text for the switch.i tried with material switch it is almost working fine except for the second text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to extend your activity with `PreferenceActivity`. Then you can use whole bunch of preferences like:

- `EditTextPreference`
- `ListPreference`
- **`SwitchPreference`**

Useful tutorial can be found at [here](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/07/android-implementing-preferences-settings-screen/). and [here](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-android-jetpack-preferences-8bcb0b7bdd14)

Answer (score 0):

for two text for swith case :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switcher"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/switcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Meeting Reminders"
            android:textColor="#111"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView

            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Meeting Reminders"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: My current solution is something like this.but in the whatsapp example we can toogle the switch even if we touch on the textviews.i know we can programmatically replicate that.i assume there will be a simple way of doing all this.thanks for your effort.